# Blank screen in Flutterflow test mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutterflow

I have created a Flutterflow project, and added a few simple widgets with a few pages. There is no database connection configured yet. There are no app state values created. There are a few hyperlinks from buttons to different pages in the app.
When I run in preview mode, everything works as expected.
But in the test mode, I see a white screen.

I used browser inspect to look for errors, but there are no errors which are new as compared to just a hello world text app which runs as expected.
I don't know how to troubleshoot this now, as there is nothing to go off of.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having to change the entry page by going into Flutterflow settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).